# Updating a column from a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-update

I'm trying to add a new column in my `Family` table called `Full Address`. It is basically combining values from other columns and generating the `Full Address`.

I wrote the below query, but it does not seem to be working. Also, I would appreciate it if there's a better way to generate my desired value- `Full Address`.

```
UPDATE Family SET FullAddress = (SELECT StreetAddress+', '+City+', '+State+', '+ZipCode AS Address FROM Family)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Keep Gap between the quote if you need more space:

```
UPDATE Family SET 
FullAddress = CONCAT(StreetAddress, ', ', City, ', ', STATE, ', ', ZipCode)
```

Comment: The nice thing about the use of CONCAT here is that it handles the case when one of more of the columns is null where as the technique presented by cmnardi and gordonlinoff does not.  The only issue with the way it handles the null is you would get , , which may not be as ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you just want this:

```
UPDATE Family
    SET FullAddress = StreetAddress + ', ' + City + ', ' + State + ', ' + ZipCode;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

`UPDATE Family SET FullAddress = StreetAddress+', '+City+', '+State+', '+ZipCode`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using SELECT, you may try to use [CONCAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) in your query:

```
UPDATE Family SET 
FullAddress = CONCAT(StreetAddress ,', ' City ,', ' STATE ,', ' ZipCode ) AS Address
```